# jQuery - Add class to each span that uses more than one line

Tags: jquery, arrays, each, parent

I got a little bit stuck on this piece of code, so I hope you can help me and this question can help others :)

What I want to accomplish is adding a class to a parent().parent() (I don't know how to call it in english) of a span that is on one than more line. 
To see if the span uses more than one line I've decided to measure the height of the span. If the span is higher than 25px, than I know for sure that it uses more than one line. Than for each span that matches that condition I want to add a class to the parent().parent() so I can style it with css.

My html looks like this:

```
<li><label><span class="abc-span">a</span><span class="text-that-is-measured">blablablablabla</span></label></li>
<li><label><span class="abc-span">b</span><span class="text-that-is-measured">blablablablabla</span></label></li>
<li><label><span class="abc-span">c</span><span class="text-that-is-measured">blablablablabla</span></label></li>
```

My script looks like this:

```
var items = [];
$('span.text-that-is-measured').each(function (i, e) {
  items.push($(e));
});

for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(items[i]);
    var spanheight = $(items[i]).height();
    if ( spanheight > 30) {
        $(items[i]).parent().parent().addClass('exampleclass');
    }
};
```

The problem is that is will only give the first `li` that matches the condition a class "exampleclass", and I want it to be on *each* `li`

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong ?

I hope my explanation was clear enough, english is not my first language.

Thanks in advance!

---

**Thanks everyone for the explanation and help!**

Comment: `parent().parent()` -> grandparent? Or any ancestor that is not the parent?

Comment: Note that you can compare to the line height of the element instead of a hard-coded value, such as `30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `closest` to get the ancestor `li`

Try this:

```
$('span.text-that-is-measured').each(function(i, e) {
    if ($(this).height() > 30) {
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('exampleclass');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.filter()` function to get span having height greater than 30px along with `.closest('li')` to get closest li(one you are referring to parent().parent()):

```
$('span.text-that-is-measured').filter(function(){
    return $(this).height() > 30; //for height higher than 30
}).closest('li').addClass('exampleclass');//add class to li element
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.closest()` to get the ancestor `li`, and then `.siblings()` to find the other `li` elements.

```
var targetListItem = $("span.text-that-is-measured").filter(function() {
    return $(this).height() > 25;
}).closest("li");
targetListItem.addClass("exampleclass");
targetListItem.siblings().addClass("exampleclass");
```

Which is a little long-winded.  Instead of working with the grandparent of the `span`, you can instead use the `.children()` of the great-grandparent.

```
$("span.text-that-is-measured").filter(function() {
    return $(this).height() > 25;
}).closest("li").parent().children().addClass("exampleClass");
```

Both of these examples are predicated on the `li` elements having a parent `ul` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work for what you want to do:

```
$('span.text-that-is-measured').each( 
    function (i, e) {  
        var spanHeight= $(e).height();  
        if ( spanHeight > 30) {
            $(e).closest('li').addClass('exampleclass');
        }
})
```